# Boxes around sponsored tags have inconsistent height

Tags: feature-request, bug, tags, design

I've noticed that sponsored tags just look terrible side-by-side with non-sponsored tags. Search [`[google-chrome] [javascript]`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-chrome+javascript) for some examples.

In case you can't see it, I've highlighted the borders around the tag box here:
[image: tag boxes]

Others might not care, but this looks pretty bad to me. The increased height is caused by the sponsor's logo. If it's removed, the box looks just like a regular tag.

Adding this CSS helps bring them back into alignment, but I'm sure a more skilled designer can come up with a better solution—this is just my first stab at it:

```
.post-tag .sponsor-tag-img {
  float: left;
  margin-top: -.3em;
  position: relative;
  top: .15em;
}
```

[image: fixed tag boxes]

I used ems because `.post-tag` has `padding: .4em .5em`, but the following works just as well:

```
.post-tag .sponsor-tag-img {
  float: left;
  margin-top: -4px;
  position: relative;
  top: 2px;
}
```

Comment: Same for [android-studio and android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-studio+android)

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the following simpler CSS fix is enough:

```css
.post-tag .sponsor-tag-img { float: left; margin-top: -2px }
```

I've added this fix to the devel branch of [SOUP](https://stackapps.com/questions/4486/stack-overflow-unofficial-patch), and, if no unexpected issue turn up (and if the bug doesn't get fixed in the mean time), it will be included in the next stable release (v1.30).